# Best way to refactor this static class in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

See this example static class below.

```
public static class BackgroundTaskExecuter
{
    public static void MethodA()
    {
        using (var service = IocManager.Instance.ResolveAsDisposable<IServiceA>())
        {
            service.Object.MethodA();
        }
    }

    public static void MethodB()
    {
        using (var service = IocManager.Instance.ResolveAsDisposable<IServiceB>())
        {
            service.Object.MethodB();
        }
    }

    public static void MethodC()
    {
        using (var service = IocManager.Instance.ResolveAsDisposable<IServiceC>())
        {
            service.Object.MethodC();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have three methods. `MethodA`, `MethodB`, and `MethodC` that correspond with three different interfaces `IServiceA`, `IServiceB`, and `IServiceC`

The reason I am doing this is because I am using Hangfire.io with aspnetboilerplate framework and in Hangfire, a background task does not have HttpContext from the normal Dependency Injection. Creating a static class that wraps my calls where I resolve manually seems to get around this.

Usage looks like this:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => BackgroundTaskExecuter.MethodA());
```

For now, I only have one or two background tasks in my web app, but conceivably I may have a lot more in the future and while it's maintainable now, it will get ugly eventually if I keep this approach.

Is there a better way to do this / refactor this? A factory pattern or anything like that perhaps?

Thanks.

Comment: @RuneFS example / hypothetical / MCVE code is off-topic on [codereview.se]. Please see [A guide to Code Review for SO users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: I would argue that this question does indeed follow the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 6):

I would make the static wrapper generic and simple.  Let it expose a single method which resolves the service and consumes it via the `using` statement, allowing for the caller to invoke the instance passed into the `Action<T>`.

**Source**

```
public static class BackgroundTaskExecuter
{
    public static void ResolveAndConsume<T>(Action<T> consumeService)
    {
        // Consider applying constraint to the <T> to 
        // match the constraint of ResolveAsDisposable<T>
        using (var service = IocManager.Instance.ResolveAsDisposable<T>())
        {
            consumeService(service);
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Usage**

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => 
    BackgroundTaskExecuter.ResolveAndConsume<IServiceA>(serviceA => serviceA.MethodA()));
```

With the above you could then resolve and consume an implementation of the service and call its functionality as desired.

Comment: The question is do all of those services have a common interface I would assume but there is no indication of that

Comment: I made an assumption that `T` would have a constraint of `IService`, but that is not necessary.  It should only follow the constraint of the `ResolveAsDisposable<T>` method.